# TailwindCSS is way too big with Angular build

Tags: css, angular, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss

When I use Tailwind to style an Angular application with a custom webpack, the styles.js chunk is huge after running `ng build`, coming in at around 30mb. This not only takes forever to build, but also slows down my web app.

After purging the Tailwind, the styles.js chunk is far smaller (~100kb), however 30mb just seems ridiculously big, even un-purged.

This even applies to a fresh application built with https://github.com/notiz-dev/ngx-tailwind, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            syntax: 'postcss-scss',
            plugins: [
              require('postcss-import'),
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ngxTailwind": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
            "outputPath": "dist/ngxTailwind",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
            "browserTarget": "ngxTailwind:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ngxTailwind:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngxTailwind:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ngxTailwind:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ngxTailwind:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ngxTailwind",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "c9efd59e-9db9-4f26-9a6f-e35b477d8e5a"
  }
}
```

styles.scss

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why it's so big? I understand it is not purged, but https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production claims the uncompressed size is under 4mb, why am I getting nearly 7 times this?

Comment: I see you mention `style.js` so you built it as development build. What's the size if you actually build it for production or with `--extract-css`?

Comment: @penleychan without purging, a production build gives a css file that is 3.52mb. This seems more reasonable, but the 30mb even in a development build just seems crazy to me.

Comment: That's just how it works with development build, reason behind it is because `style.css` is not a valid javascript module, so it need something to change css module to js module, and that is loaders. So `style.js` has all your css and includes javascript loaders

Comment: @penleychan, I definitely expected it to be bigger, but 30mb?? It just makes developing a pain as it takes around a minute to build whenever any styling changes are made. When I use Bootstrap, the styles.js is far smaller, and the build time is much quicker.

Comment: I also experience the same issue. It's not normal as uncompressed tailwind is around 3MB. It's like it's included 10 times !? @JacobSwetmore Did you manage to find the root cause ?

Answer (score 8):

Just change tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}']
  },
  //Other Code
};
```

then build: `ng build --prod`

Reference: [Enabling manually](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#setting-up-purgecss)

Comment: My .css was 5mb. After "enabled: true" it's 145kb. Thanks.